# Laravel not uploading all images

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to upload some images from my Vue.js app to Laravel, and so far I made some things happen, but not all of them...

When I try to upload an image, it's uploading only a first selected image, others are stored in database but not in storage folder, and I have no idea why. Here is how my code looks like:

```
public function storeImages()
    {
        foreach ($this->images as $key => $image) {
            $file_name = 'image_'.time().'.png';
            @list($type, $image) = explode(';', $image);
            @list(, $image)      = explode(',', $image);

            if($image!=""){
                Storage::disk('productImages')->put($file_name, base64_decode($image));
            }

            Images::create([
                'products_id' => $this->product_id,
                'path' => $file_name,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

So it seems to pass every image, because every image is stored in database, what could be a problem here?

Comment: seems like the problem is here `'image_'.time().'.png';`, try with this `'image_'.time() . rand() .'.png'`

Comment: Could be, will change now

Comment: Or use `microtime()`. Then there will be no extra characters in the name of the image.

Answer (score 2):

Because the image replaces with every loop, for the same name `'image_'.time().'.png';`, give a random name can fix the problem :

```
'image_'.time().rand().'.png'
```

Comment: Good answer :) Another alternative would be something like `uniqid()`: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php